# Invoking particular class of native app from service app in Tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

Is there any API to invoke a particular class of native app from service app in Tizen?

From service app i can able to invoke native app but not the particular class

by using the code

```
AppId callerAppId = L"someId";
    AppManager* pAppManager = AppManager::GetInstance();
    result res=pAppManager->LaunchApplication(callerAppId, AppManager::LAUNCH_OPTION_DEFAULT);
```

But i want to invoke particular class just like broad cast receivers in Android

Answer (score 0):

On Tizen platform to communicate another application (or application subprocess) you need to use AppControl and related interfaces. Here's documentation for it:

[AppControl for native application](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1App_1_1AppControl.html)

[AppControl for web application](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/application.html#%3a%3aApplication%3a%3aApplicationControl)

[AppControl usage sample in web application](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/app/appcontrol_email.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

Inside service app(Calling App) of on initialising method  add the below code

```
Tizen::App::AppControl* pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(L"Nativeapplication id",
                                                          L"");
    if (pAc)
    {
       pAc->Start(null, null, null, null);

       delete pAc;
   }
```

Above code finds the native application installed on your device

Add the following code inside your Native application form of on initialising method to register setapp control provider
AppControlProviderManager::GetInstance()->SetAppControlProviderEventListener(this);

Inside on app control request received just invoke your class or form
    void NativeapplicationMainForm::OnAppControlRequestReceived     (   RequestId   reqId,
        const Tizen::Base::String &     operationId,
        const Tizen::Base::String *     pUriData,
        const Tizen::Base::String *     pMimeType,
        const Tizen::Base::Collection::IMap *   pExtraData
    )
    {
    //invoke your form or class

```
}



    AppLog("invoked Native app from service app");


}
```